# Could not fulfill request (error code 7) via openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions with Facebook test users

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

### Background

- Recently upgraded to Facebook SDK **3.2**
- Tested on both device and simulator (iOS **5.1** through **6.1**)
- Error is only present when attempting to authenticate Facebook **test users**.

### Error

> The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Temporarily unable to make API calls on behalf of XXXXXX.
>
> UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7}

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Clear simulator or manually remove Facebook account from device settings.
2. Create a test user via Facebook's *accounts/test-users* endpoint.
3. Add Facebook account in device settings.
4. Authenticate via openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions & accept the permissions dialog.

### Expected Result

- FBSessionStateHandler block returns with state == FBSessionStateOpen.
- A nil NSError.

### Actual Result

- FBSessionStateHandler block returns with a error.fberrorCategory == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled with the above user info trace.

### Solution Attempts

- I've followed the steps outlined in [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12644229/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor); namely checking my bundle name, ensuring my app type is set to **Native/Desktop** and setting my **App Secret in Client** to NO.
- As well, I have ensured I am only asking for read permissions (ie. email).
- I've even bypassed the Facebook SDK altogether by attempting to authentication with a **ACAccountStore** instance & got the same results.
- Again, everything works fine with a regular user (non-test); so it must have something to do with the configuration & recent 3.2 changes.

Comment: Be sure to have your Facebook app in "sandbox mode" and use a "admin" or "tester" facebook account. You can add admins/testers to your facebook app in developer.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

1) Facebook 3.1 SDK splits read and publish permissions. Use only read permissions (e.g., email) in the first authentication call. Using both will break it and result in that generic error. It seems Facebook's SDK doesn't actually do what it's meant to do: fall back to older authentication methods. David tells me an updated Parse SDK will make the permissions split easier, but it will of course be up to Facebook to fix that bug in their SDK.

2) Independently, the issue I was having seems to have gone away after signing out of Facebook in the device's Settings, and then back in. Maybe a glitch in the iOS integration? (The permissions split issue still applies here, however. Make sure you do read first and publish (e.g., publish_actions) separately later, the first time you actually need it.)